# canvas, trigger mouse event

Tags: canvas, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I'm trying to understand a code for a canvas example :

Why is the third parameter "false" in the eventhandler code? What does it stand for?

Here the complete code

```
function init () {
// ...
// Attach the mousemove event handler.
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_mousemove, false);
}

// The mousemove event handler.
var started = false;
function ev_mousemove (ev) {
  var x, y;

// Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
    x = ev.layerX;
    y = ev.layerY;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is part of code missing. As you said the variable started is set but not used that's why I feel there's some code part missing (also a closing-brace is missing after the ev_mousemove function).

The ev.layerX == 0 is just after || which means "OR". That is used that way so it doesn't create an error in Firefox. Basically it says if the ev.layerX is true (existing) OR if is 0 do...

ND

Answer (score 1):

**The third true/false parameter in AddEventListener is used to "Capture" events**

If true, then the your "mousemove" events will always *first* go to *your* ev_mousemove and *then* go to the normal DOM event tree.

If false, then your "mousemove" events will just go through the normal DOM event tree.

Unless you have a reason to prioritize your your own event handler, you can usually leave this as false for any kind of events.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I also found a link about it: [link]http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=827